# Conditional Expectation in Uniform Case

Tags: conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution, bounds

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables where $X \sim uniform[\underline{x}, \bar x]$ and $Y \sim uniform[\underline{y}, \bar y]$.

What is the conditional expectation of $X$ given $z = X + Y$?

Here are my thoughts so far:

$$
E[X|X + Y = z] = \int^{\bar x}_{\underline{x}} x f_{X|Z}(x|z)dx
= \int^{\bar x}_{\underline{x}} \frac{x f_{X,Z}(x,z)}{f_{Z}(z)}dx
$$

We can find $f_Z$ using convolution:

$$f_Z(z) = \int^{\bar x}_{\underline{x}} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx = \int^{\text{min}\{\bar x, z-\underline{y}\}}_{\text{max}\{\underline{x}, z - \bar y\}} \frac{1}{(\bar x - \underline{x})(\bar y - \underline{y})}dx = \frac{\text{min}\{\bar x, z-\underline{y}\} - \text{max}\{\underline{x}, z - \bar y\}}{(\bar x - \underline{x})(\bar y - \underline{y})}$$

We can find $f_{X,Z}$ using a transformation on $f_{X,Y}$:

$$f_{X,Z}(x,z) = f_{X,Y}(u_1^{-1}(p,q),u_2^{-1}(p,q))|J_u|^{-1}$$

Here, $p = u_1(x,y) = x$, $q = u_2(x,y) = x+y$, $x = u_1^{-1}(p,q) = p$, $y = u_2^{-1}(p,q) = q-p$. Additionally, $J_u = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y} \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x} = 1$. Thus, $f_{X,Z}(x,z) = f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.

This gives me the following expression for $E[X|X + Y = z]$:

$$
E[X|X + Y = z] = \frac{\int^{\text{min}\{\bar x, z-\underline{y}\}}_{\text{max}\{\underline{x}, z - \bar y\}} \frac{x}{(\bar x - \underline{x})(\bar y - \underline{y})} dx}{\int^{\text{min}\{\bar x, z-\underline{y}\}}_{\text{max}\{\underline{x}, z - \bar y\}} \frac{1}{(\bar x - \underline{x})(\bar y - \underline{y})}dx} = \frac{\text{min}\{\bar x, z-\underline{y}\} - \text{max}\{\underline{x}, z - \bar y\}}{2}
$$

However, this answer does not make sense as the conditional expectation of $X$ after observing $X+Y$. For example, after observing $z = \bar x + \bar y$, $x$ must be $\bar x$, but the expression I came to gives 0 for this case.

I'm thinking something went wrong when I tried to find $f_{X,Z}$, or there is an issue with the integral bounds somewhere.

Comment: By drawing a suitable diagram of the joint distribution you can write the correct (albeit somewhat complicated) answer *by visual inspection only.*  Simply observe that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Z$ must itself be uniform, so all you need to know is the interval of its support.

Comment: The "-" sign must be "+": $E[X|X + Y = z] = \frac{\text{min}\{\bar x, z-\underline{y}\} + \text{max}\{\underline{x}, z - \bar y\}}{2}$